# Data too long for column though the right value

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, mybatis

hello I have been wondered this issue so far.
below is the error code.

```
### SQL: INSERT INTO student    (id, name, student_data)   VALUES    (?, ?, ?)
### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'student_data' at row 1
; SQL []; Data truncation: Data too long for column 'student_data' at row 1; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'student_data' at row 1
```

`student_data` in `student` table is mediumTEXT.
and the input data is about 74,000 bytes.

It is too enough to enter the data in the table. I don't want to change `sql_mode`, and packet size is about 1G I specified. I think it is perfect to perform without an error.

what is the wrong on my code?

## Here is the DDL

```sql
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `student_data` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: @Strawberry I don't think it is relevant other tables. and I already wrote that column format 'mediumTEXT'

Comment: Why can't you change MEDIUMTEXT to LONGTEXT?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the below table structure

```
 CREATE TABLE `student` (
`id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
`name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`student_data` longtext NOT NULL
 )
```

Comment: of course I thought this way but it didn't work and too long size
even though it works, I cannot modify mediumTEXT -> longTEXT

Comment: Can you just try storing only limited text? I mean while binding the data student_data you can use `ltrim($student_data)`